# Converting from double to int with correct rounding

Tags: java

ok i have some thing like this:

```
int x = 5;  
int y = 3;  
int z = Math.round(x/y);
```

and output ends up being 1 even though it should be 2, yes i have imported Math
I have tried stuff like:

```
int z = (int) ((x/y) + 0.5)
```

but it doesn't work and continues being 1
I have also looked through this site for about half an hour and tried all the solutions that I found, some worked but when I changed `x` and `y` a little it rounded up instead of down.
`x` and `y` should actually be random numbers(that is the way it is in my actual program) but i have it simplified for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by the time you pass a value to `round()` the "horse is already out of the barn: integer division chops off the fractional part, so `Math.round()` gets a clean `1`, which it happily returns.

Casting `x` or `y` to `double` before the call will let you achieve the expected result:

```
int z = Math.round(((double)x)/y);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give 2, because you are doing integer arithmetic and so (5/3) will be 1 in integer arithmetic.

So my advice is to cast any one of operands.

Ex.

```
Math.round((double)x/y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this :

> ```
>     System.out.println("Math.round(5/3) " + Math.round(5 / 3));
>     System.out.println("Math.round(5.0/3.0) " + Math.round(5.0 / 3.0));
> ```

output :

```
1
2
```

EDIT : so yes you need to cast at least one